# Unsigned long in Rails/MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to force having the primary key (id) generated as unsigned bigint, by inserting the following in environment.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
```

But when I try to generate a migration, I get the following error message:

```
/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby -e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) "/projects/test/script/rails" generate migration Ball name:string last:string -s
/projects/test/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter (NameError)
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
    from /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
    from /projects/test/script/rails:6:in `require'
    from /projects/test/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

When I take that line out of environment.rb, the migration works, but obviously the primary key is set to int, not unsigned bigint. Any ideas?

Comment: A file in `config/initializers` might be a better spot for this. `environment.rb` is really early in the loading cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this require statement on top of your environment file

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter'
```

Comment: Did that, and now I'm getting the following error: rake aborted!
mysql is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile. In my gemfile, I have gem 'mysql2' and when I check for installed gems, it's there: mysql2 (0.3.11)

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` from the root directory of your application?